# How to best implement and structure a view in an ASP.NET MVC app to have better caching across page loads?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a web app with several pages that functions as a data administration console. You can lookup data against our DB, create new entities, edit, delete, etc. It is created in ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor.

I'm having trouble with my form post data being "lost" (not applied) between visits to the same view.

### Background

The site structure is fairly typical with several views -- one for home, then one for each of the different entities (let's call them Parent, Child)

- The Home view as a search field were you can search for Parent elements.  When you submit the search, the parent entities that match are shown in an HTML table.

[image]

- In the HTML table, there is actions next to each Parent row, to edit it, or show the children.  If you click on `Show Children`, it does another form post to show the children for that parent row. E.g:

[image]

At first, I tried using multiple forms on the Home view: one for `search`, one for the each of the rows in the `parent` table, and one for each row in the `children` table.  However, this caused problems with caching -- when I chose to edit one of the rows (going to the corresponding view to do that), when I got sent back to the Home view, the previous search wasn't still applied so I had to restart my search.  I found that if I kept a single form for the entire page, caching worked properly, so as I dived in and out editing entities caching seemed to work (and improved overall usability).

So the code I have is roughly the following (I've edited it a lot to simplify it for this question):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post ))
{
  <div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTerm )
    <input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
  <h2>Parents</h2>
  <div>
    @{
      var parents = Tool.Models.ToolsModelService.SearchParents(Model.SearchTerm);
    }
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
        <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Parent ID</th>
             <th>Attribute 1</th>
             <th>Attribute 2</th>
             <th>Actions</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach (var p in parents)
          {
            <tr>
               <td>@p.ID</td>
               <td>@p.Name</td>
               <td>@p.Attrib1</td>
               <td>@p.Attrib2</td>
               <td>
                 <input type="hidden" name="SelectedParent" value="@p.ID.ToString()" />
                 <input type="submit" name="ParentSubmit" value="Edit" />
                 <input type="submit" name="ChildrenSubmit" value="Show Children" />
               </td>
            </tr>
           }
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" name="ParentSubmit" value="Add">Add New Parent</button>
  </div>
  @if (Model.SelectedParent != null)
  {
    var children = Tool.Models.ToolModelService.GetChildren(Model.SelectedParent);
    if (children != null && children.Count > 0)
    {
      <h2>Children</h2>
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Child ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Action</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           @foreach (var c in children)
           {
             <tr>
               <td>@c.ID</td>
               <td>@c.Name</td>
               <td>
               @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
               {
                  <input type="hidden" name="SelectedChild" value="@c.ID.ToString()" />
                  <input type="submit" name="ChildrenSubmit" value="Edit" />
               }
               </td>    
             </tr>
           }
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="submit" name="MenuItemSubmit" value="Add">Add new child</button>
       </div>
    }
  }
  else
  {
    <h2>Children</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Select a parent to show children for<p>
    </div>
  }
```

In the `HomeController.cs`, there is a bunch of code. Here is some of the form handling:

```
...

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model)
{
    model = new HomeModel();
    this.LoadState(model);
    return View(model);
}

[ActionName("Index")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[AcceptParameter(Name = "SearchSubmit", Value = "Search")]
public ActionResult Register_Search(HomeModel model)
{
    ActionResult action;
    this.CacheState(model);
    action = this.View(model);
    return action;
}

[ActionName("Index")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[AcceptParameter(Name = "ParentSubmit", Value = "Add")]
public ActionResult Register_ParentAdd(HomeModel model)
{
    this.CacheState(model);
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Parent");
}

...

private void CacheState(HomeModel model)
{
    this.Session[CachedModelKey] = model;
}

private void LoadState(HomeModel model)
{
   if (null != this.Session[CachedModelKey])
   {
       var cachedModel = (HomeModel)this.Session[CachedModelKey];
       model.SearchTerm = cachedModel.SearchTerm;
       model.SelectedRestaurant = cachedModel.SelectedParent;
       model.SelectedMenuItem = cachedModel.SelectedChild;
   }
}
```

### Problems

I'm having various problems, and I'm positive it's due to me being very new to ASP.NET MVC and how to properly set everything up in my code.

1. The `parents` table form doesn't work correctly. If I click on `Show children` for anything row, it always shows the children for the first row.
2. If I search for Parent1, chose it's children, then edit one of the child items (which is on a separate view).  I eventually get sent back to the Home view, but the search is no longer applied -- this is what I mean by "caching"; my form post values aren't being persisted across reloads of the view in all cases.

I have to search again for `parent1` which slows the workflow down. I really want to persist the searches so I don't have re-search to bring up the same child list (makes it simpler to keep editing multiple children for same parent)

I'm sure I'm missing something here really straightforward, so would appreciate some help that would solve the above problems, but also any advice on better ways to structure things.  If I'm missing any info, let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by caching... You can use something like Session data or a cookie to set up the home page and reapply the search. Just change the redirect url to append the necessary information

Comment: @AndrewBurgess: ASP.NET can use `CacheState()` to cache session data which is what I'm using in my controller. It works sometimes, but not always.

Comment: What do you mean by "caching" and why do you need it?

Comment: Question not clear indeed... Anyway for what I understand, you would be better off by eliminating all those forms for each row and making a ajax call instead.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev: I clarified the original question a bit more. By "caching" I just mean that my form post isn't persisted 100% of the time across multiple visits to the same view. IOW, sometimes it is and sometimes it isn't and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @GiorgioBozio: I don't want to do that many changes, I'd like to stay within the form post structure I have, hence my question.

Comment: @TMC What do you mean by "persisted"? Persisted *where*? Have you tried using `Session` or database?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev: In my code I listed above, you can `HomeController.cs` uses `this.CacheState(model)` and `this.LoadState(model)`.  I described what I meant by "persisted" in my question: I mean that I apply a search or a load of child items for a parent, edit a child and come back to the home view.  I want the previous form post still applied.

Comment: @TMC Have you tried using `Session` or database? What does `CacheState` and `LoadState` do? Where do you get them from? I could not find them in MSDN.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot I implemented methods of my own called `CacheState` and 'LoadState' which uses `Session` to save the state. I updated the question with this detail.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to handle this type of page would be to use [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)
In Backbone you can set up client side views that are bound to html templates.
You load your model data into the templates and then render the view.

You can wire up events in your backbone view which can listen to changes on your backbone model and then render the appropriate view showing the changes.

Backbone has a learning curve but if you start from a pre-built example you will get the hang of it. Definitely worth learning as it would be a perfect fit for your page.

Rob Conery has done a nice example here...
http://wekeroad.com/2011/08/11/the-backbonejs-todo-list-sample-refactored-part-1/

Caching wise I would make your viewmodel objects serializable and then Cache the objects
using System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache against a key constructed from your search parameters. This will avoid uneccessary trips to the database.